# Electron reuse command line args when use open -a

Tags: macos, google-chrome, electron

`test.app` is an app design by Electron, which can receive command line args，when i try those steps：

```
1 open -n /Applications/test.app --args www.stackoverflow.com
2 open -a /Applications/test.app --args www.stackoverflow.com
3 close /Applications/test.app
4 open test.app from LaunchPad
5 ps aux | grep /Applications/test.app
6 test.app process has argments: /Applications/test/app www.stackoverflow.com
```

why test.app has argments when i open it form LaunchPad? how to disable this features？

PS： I find chrome has this feature too

Comment: When you are closing your app you are just closing the renderer window. The [main.js](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/blob/master/main.js#L44-L45) from the electron-quick-start example shows that behaviour more clearly: On all platforms, except macOS, the app quits. On macOS however, the renderer-window is just closed and the main-process keeps on running, waiting for the `activate` event to initiate a new renderer-window. And since the main-process never really is closed it keeps the passed arguments.

Comment: thx, but when i use ps aux after  close /Applications/test.app, there is no any process names test running